# PowerShell 5.1 Is it possible to pass table results from Invoke-Sqlcmd into another as a parameter?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

PowerShell 5.1
Sql Server 2016 or newer

Is it possible to take `DataTable` results from one `Invoke-Sqlcmd` and pass it in as a parameter?

(Incomplete)

```
$OutputTbl = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from customer" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables


$sql2 = "
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (Id int, FirstName nvarchar(50), City nvarchar(50)) = $OutputTbl

Select * from @OutputTbl
"
$res2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sql2 -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables


$res2
```

## Update:

Trying with ADO.Net library

```
$dt = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from customer" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables


$sql2 = "
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (Id int, FirstName nvarchar(50), City nvarchar(50)) 

INSERT INTO @OutputTbl
select * from @dt


select * from @OutputTbl
"
$params = 
@{
    'dt' = $dt 
} 
$conn = New-Connection '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB' -database 'Database1' 
$res2 = Invoke-Query -connection $conn -sql $sql2 -parameters $params


$res2
```

[image]

Comment: Probably easier using DBA-Tools's function `Invoke-DbaQuery` [along with a Table Valued Parameter](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery#example-9). But why bother when you can just do the whole thing in one batch in the first place? Why bring the data into Powershell only to send it back again?

Comment: I don't believe Invoke-Sqlcmd is advanced enough to handle table-valued parameters. You could use a .NET [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand) object and pass in the DataTable via an [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) with the [\[System.Data.SqlDbType\]::Structured DbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype).